# Yacc Problem: Make Data available in next Non Terminal

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, generator

I want to make some variables I generate in b available in c:

```
a   :   b c { ...some code...}
```

A simple example:

```
b :  X  { int result = 0; } 
  |  Y  { int result = 1; }
```

so I can, later on in c say:

```
c : D   { printf(result + 1); }
  | E   { printf(result + 2);  }
```

Is there any chance to do that? Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393104/yacc-code-after-each-non-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` should be a global variable. You can do this by including

```
%{
    int result;
%}
```

at the top of your YACC file. Of course, you should also replace `int result = 0` and `int result = 1` with `result = 0` and `result = 1` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Can suggested, however generally it is not a good idea to use globals in syntax rules. Declare a type for `b` and `c` so your rules look like this:

```
%union {
    int result;
};

%type <result> a b

%start a

%%

b : X {$$ = 0;} | Y {$$ = 1;} ;
c : D {$$ = 1;} | E {$$ = 2;} ;
a : b c {printf("%d", $1 + $2);};
```