# Yacc: Code after each non-terminal

Tags: yacc

Is there a way to execute code after each Terminal?

So that something like this is possible:

```
a : B { code } C { some code }
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393041/yacc-problem-make-data-available-in-next-non-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I some how didn't get that C is $3 after inserting the code and not $2... really odd.

Comment: That's the important catch; $2 is effectively the code block.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include this as explanation, and then delete this response.